# XML parsing - Array with value Class

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, serialization

I have an XML file that can look something like this:

```
<complex>
    <complex>Value</complex>
    <complex>
       <field>Value</field>
    </complex>
</complex>
```

Now, the class for field look something like this:

```
[XmlElement]
public List<Field> field { get; set; }


public class Field
{

[XmlAttribute]
public string name;

[XmlAttribute("ref")]
public string reference;

[XmlText]
public string value;

}
```

I would like to parse both the value of the complex, as well as the children of the complex.

I assume complex is both an array and something else?

I would appreciate any input!

Comment: Your question is not clear, you should provide more input.

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studio's "Paste XML as classes" produces this (after I made it a little more succinct):

```
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class complex {

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("complex")]
        public complexComplex[] complex1 { get; set; }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
        public partial class complexComplex {

            public string field { get; set; }

            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
            public string[] Text { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Is this what you are after?